# [Vertica][VJDBC](3457) ERROR: Function ParquetExportFinalize(int) does not exist, or permission is denied for ParquetExportFinalize(int)

Tags: vertica

I got the following error when trying to export to parquet in vertica

> [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Function ParquetExportFinalize(int) does not exist, or permission is denied for ParquetExportFinalize(int)

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT ALL ON LIBRARY public.ParquetExportLib to user;
GRANT ALL ON TRANSFORM FUNCTION public.ParquetExport(int) TO user;
GRANT ALL ON TRANSFORM FUNCTION public.ParquetExportMulti(int) TO user;
GRANT ALL ON TRANSFORM FUNCTION public.ParquetExportFinalize(int) TO user;
```

Comment: explanation of code would make this a much better answer

Comment: @workabyte the "code" self-explanatory. A sentence like "you have to grant all privs for library xyz to user abc" won't add any information